# Improving Performance with large Data Sizes in RMySQL & R

Tags: r, rmysql

I need to create a Data Downloader which may be asked to fetch from a few 1000s to 30-40 Million records.

In RMySQL, I am currently fetching a constant size of 4000 records in every round using below Code:

```
rs = dbSendQuery(con, query)
  totRow = 0
  resultDF = data.frame()
  while (!dbHasCompleted(rs)) {
    chunk <- dbFetch(rs, 4000)
    resultDF<-rbind(resultDF, chunk)
    totRow = totRow + nrow(chunk)

    #Status Print
    if(totRow %% 100000 == 0){
      print(paste(OutFile, format(totRow, scientific=F)))
    }
  }
  dbClearResult(rs)
```

Since, I am doing a rbind every time, this methods slows down horribly for large data sizes. What can be better approach? Does RMySQL support returning how many records are present in result?

I was thinking of performing the fetch with a dynamic size, which keeps increasing with every fetch, just like C++ Vectors. Are there any better alternatives here?

Comment: I believe if you allocate the entire size of the data object first, for instance, `resultDF = data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow(object), ncol(object)))`, then assign chunks as `resultDF[totRow:(totRow + nrow(chunk),] = chunk`, it should be faster

Comment: How to know, the size of object being returned? I have asked that above as well: "Does RMySQL support returning how many records are present in result?"